# Proving a harmonic denominator is largest number NOT divisible by a number $y$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Given the [Harmonic Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicSeries.html):

$$\sum_{k=1}^x 1/k = \frac{n}{d}$$

and then simplifying the resulting fraction, how can I *prove* that the denominator $d$ is the largest one in the series that is **not** divisible by a given number $y$?

For example, [2933773379069966367528193600, the 68th denominator, is apparently the largest one not divisible by 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=541).  I'm not sure how this can be guaranteed as true any more than me making the claim that 9999999999999999 is the largest number divisible by 9.

*Note that I'm not looking for an answer to the Euler question. I'm trying to understand how such a claim can be proven.*

Comment: The Euler problems are supposed to encourage exploration.  The denominators are given in http://oeis.org/A002805  I would start by looking at the recurrence given in the notes, compute it around $68$ and try to understand how it happens that $3$ divides all the rest when this didn't happen earlier.

Comment: @Ross after trying to figure out a pattern between the 65th and 73rd numbers, I'm just not seeing anything.  This may just be out of my mathematical expertise, but I'm honestly not seeing anything that would definitively prove that all future numbers must be divisible by 3.