# Harmonic Denominator Not Divisible by $3$

Tags: number-theory

This is in relation to my previous question [Dividing Harmonic Number's Denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819796/dividing-harmonic-numbers-denominator). The answer there says that they "found no $H_n$ with denominator not divisibly by 3 for $68<n\le 10000$. How can one be sure that the rest of $H_n$ has a denominator that is divisible by $3$, i.e. how can we say for sure that $H_{68}$ is the last occurrence where the denominator is **not** divisible by $3$?

Comment: @gammatester Can you give your thoughts on this question?

Comment: Using @ won't notify someone who has not already posted to this question. Anyway, maybe we *can't* say for sure the rest of them have denominator divisible by 3. Maybe it's a really hard, unsolved problem.

Comment: Note also that the question has been asked (but not answered) previously, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602142/proving-a-harmonic-denominator-is-largest-number-not-divisible-by-a-number-y

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was just experimenting and tried some calculations, and I came across this sequence: https://oeis.org/A229493. If you look in the example, there are three numbers 2,7,22. Let S(n) be some function that gives the maximum index of the harmonic sequence such that it does not divide n where n is prime. So in this questions case we have n=3. So S(3)=22*3+(3-1)=68. I tried this formula out for n=5 and n=7 and it works, but where do those numbers come from, and how can they be certain to stop at 22 in the case of 3?

Comment: Keith Conrad states, but doesn't prove, that 3 divides every denominator past 68 (and does lots of other interesting stuff) in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/padicharmonicsum.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes that paper is interesting indeed. In the paper it mentions $J(p)$. Can we come up with a general form for that? I'm having trouble understanding where he comes up with the set of value for $p=3,5,7$ and how he can say that $p=11$ has 638 elements?